# How can i increase my quantity fields when users viewed second times on the same page

Tags: python, django

*models.py*

```
class ProductDetailHistory(models.Model):
    user                     = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    viewed_product_detail_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    viewed_product_quantity  = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    timestamp                = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

*views.py*

```
class ProductDetail(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = self.request.user
        product_detail_id = request.GET.get('itemId')
        ProductDetailHistory.objects.create(user=user,
                                            viewed_product_detail_id=product_detail_id)
```

here i want to update the quantity when the user views the product which he/she already viewed once if already created this users objects

but i have no idea to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)** method. If it gets the object then it will update the quantity otherwise it will create the new object.

```
from django.db.models import F

obj, created=ProductDetailHistory.objects.get_or_create(user=user, viewed_product_detail_id=product_detail_id)
if obj:
   obj.viewed_product_quantity = F('viewed_product_quantity') + 1
   obj.save()
```